# Python exchangelib how to get today's unread mail list?

Tags: python, exchangelib

I'm trying to get only today's unread mail list by using Python `exchanglib` library.
My code is like this below:

```
from exchangelib import Account,Credentials
import time

def connect_mail(username, pwd, addr):
    credentials = Credentials(username=username, password=pwd)
    account = Account(addr, credentials=credentials, autodiscover=True)
    return account

def get_unread_mail(account):
    res = account.inbox.filter(is_read=False)
    return res

a = connect_mail(username, pwd, addr)   
unread_mail_list = get_unread_mail(a)
current_date = time.strftime("%Y%m%d", time.localtime()) 
curr_mail_list = []
for mail in unread_mail_list :
    if str(mail.datetime_received)[:10].replace('-','') == current_date:
        curr_mail_list .append(mail)
```

This code may work , but actually this code will run for a long time cause i've a plenty of unread mails in my inbox.

And then I wanna solve it by using `.filter()`.

Code is like this:

```
from exchangelib import EWSDate, EWSDateTime

def today_mail(account):
    today = EWSDate.today()
    mails = account.inbox.all().filter(start__gte=today)
    return mails
```

Or:

```
def today_mail(account):
    start = account.default_timezone.localize(EWSDateTime(2020, 6, 29))
    end = account.default_timezone.localize(EWSDateTime(2020, 7, 1))
    mails = account.inbox.all().filter(start__range=(start,end))
```

But unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Can anyone give me a hand on this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Messages don't have `start` and `end` fields. That is for calendar items.

Instead, filter on one of the `Message` timestamp fields mentioned in https://ecederstrand.github.io/exchangelib/#message-timestamp-fields, for example `datetime_received`.

Comment: Thanks for your heads up. I 've used `datetime_received` before (like:`a.inbox.filter(is_read=False).order_by('_datetime_received')[:100]`), but that was not what I need. And I cannot read all the unread mails first and then add a timestamp filter on, just like my first code.

Comment: That example code orders, but doesn't filter, on `datetime_received`. And why can't you filter on both fields? `a.inbox.filter(is_read=False, datetime_received__gte=last_midnight)` should do what you want.

Comment: That works! Thank u .And I've solved this by using `from openpyxl import Q`  to filter on more fields.

Comment: Sorry for a typing error :)  by using `from exchangelib import Q`